# WiFi connectivity issue with Intel 7265: disconnecting on a regular basis

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, iwlwifi

I have this wireless connectivity problem with my Asus Zenbook UX305UA running ubuntu 20.04 in a WiFi-network spun by a [Fritz!Box 7530](https://en.avm.de/products/fritzbox/fritzbox-7530/technical-data/) router. The PC establishes a WiFi connection but gets disconnected after a while (5 to 20min). The problem gets much worse, the further away the notebook is (10m to 30m distance). The connection does not seem to recover but when I force the NetworkManager to reconnect, it works fine for a while again.

Reading through the internet, I suspect that it is an issue with the network card choking on the newer WiFi-standard (the problem occurred since I changed my router). Other OS – including an old MacBook – have no problem in the WiFi.

[This youtube-post](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0pQBl0AZEE) explains the problem quite precise. The notebook has a *Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)* network controller. It seems that there occurred such problems quite frequently with the 7265D-family, but all used Windows (sometimes, the problem was a clumsy update of Windows, which was solved when either Windows or the (latest) Intel driver was reinstalled manually).
I am using the [*Intel Wireless WiFi driver for Linux* driver (iwlwifi)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) (Kernel 5.4.0.67).

[The Linux wireless site](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#and_7265_support) explains that:

> [7260, 3160, 7265, 7265D, 3165 and 3168] Those devices will not be supported by the newest firmware versions: the last firmware that was released for 3160, 7260 and 7265 is -17.ucode. Bug fixes will be ported to -17.ucode. **7265D**, 3165 and 3168's **latest firmware version is -29.ucode**.

which is what I have already installed. So the advice to upgrade the *iwlfifi* driver as most posts suggested (such as [this post on ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726292/cant-connect-wifi-with-intel-ac-7265-on-ubuntu-15-10-asus-zenbook-ux305?rq=1)) is somewhat already done.

**Update**
[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/583574/intel-dual-band-wireless-7265-dropping-connection/803452#803452) suggested an upgrade of the `iwlwifi`-driver. However, the links are outdated and my version is much newer (driver version 5.4.0-70-generic). According to the comments, the problem remains today (with newer driver versions and newer operating systems).

Answer (score 0):

Set unused wifi channel, in router/modem, in nearby areas [ type
nmcli dev wifi
in terminal to find wifi channels in use].

If still disconnecting,

Try reserving ip address in router's lan settings for the zenbook

Can also put manual ip address, netmask, gateway in ipv4 and / or ipv6 wifi settings for the network in ubuntu settings.

Comment: I appreciate the ideas. Unfortunately, it is my neighbors router (I will get patched in two weeks), so changes in the router settings are not an option. Since the issue does not occur on other hardware (and OS), I thought that the problem is on my side anyway